# How do I send HTTP requests over a TCPSocket?

Tags: ruby, http, tcp

I've written a class in `Ruby` that acts as an HTTP client. The code is minimal but the reason I'm not using `'net/http'` is because this method allowes me to have more control over the requests being made and documentation for the HTTP is not helpful at all.

Anyway, the problem is the socket will only work for one request and response. Sending a second or subsequent request gives me an empty response.

For example:

1. Open connection to google
2. GET "/"
3. Response is the google.ca html
4. GET "/"
5. Response is empty

I tried closing and opening the connection between the requests but that only slowed it down and didn't fix the problem. I still got empty responses.

So what is the problem here?

Is there a method that lets me check to see if the `TCPSocket` object has an open connection so I don't accidentally open a new one?

Comment: Without code examples it's really hard to be specific. Rather than reinvent a well covered wheel, why not look at Ruby's `open-uri`, or the typhoeus, httpclient or curb gems?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
require "socket"
host = "google.com"
port = 80
socket = TCPSocket.new host,port
request = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost:#{host}\r\n\r\n"
socket.print request
response = socket.read
```

This will return Google's main page.  If you want to send request after request then change it to "HTTP/1.1" and read a response, then send the next request.